# What is the maximum level?

Tags: borderlands-2

What is the maximum level in the game and how many skill points will I have at maximum level?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

> **This answer is outdated as of the 2019 Commander Lilith DLC, as noted in [this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/352532/8350)**

The max level in the Borderlands 2 base game is 50, giving you 45 skill points to spend. Gearbox actually has a character planner on their website (which can be found [here](http://www.borderlands2.com/us/skilltree/)) that should help you pick out your skills.

Borderlands 2's "Ultimate Vault Hunter Upgrade Pack", available for $5 (or as part of the Season Pass DLC) can be purchased to increase the level cap from 50 to 61.

The Ultimate Vault Hunter Upgrade Pack **2**: Digistruct Peak Challenge DLC further pushes the level cap to 72 for those who own it.

Comment: Looking at the [char editor](http://www.borderlands2.com/us/skilltree/commando.html), you have 46 points to spend. You forgot the point at level 5?

Comment: @WernerCD I didn't count the point at level 5 because that's the one you need to spend on your action skill to unlock your skill trees in the first place. Technically speaking though, you do get 46 skill points.

Comment: @DiabloMonkey The level cap with UVHPack is sixty **one**. Can you please link to something proving it is 65?

Answer (score 11):

As of the release of the [Commander Lilith & the Fight for Sanctuary](https://borderlands.com/en-US/shop/borderlands-2-commander-lilith-and-the-fight-for-sanctuary/) DLC on 2019-06-09, the level cap has been increased to 80.