# Further skill points and levels in borderlands 2

Tags: borderlands-2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the maximum level?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/85420/what-is-the-maximum-level)

Is it possible to get more than level 50 in borderlands 2 in any way? Maybe dlc?
Or is it possible to gain extra skill points to unlock further skills?

I know there was doc for borderlands 1 but can't find anything about borderlands 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the time of this question (after Mr. Torgue's Campaign of Carnage DLC), there is no way past level 50.  That may change with future dlc.  As for extra skill points, the only way is through Class Mods.