# How has combat changed from Borderlands to Borderlands 2?

Tags: borderlands-2, borderlands, borderlands-series

I might rephrase it as, "*What are things that a BL1 player should know jumping into BL2?*"

Not all of these are probably worth answering in regards to the main question, but here are some examples:

- I seem to recall that aim assist is default on in Borderlands 1. I don't like to play with aim assist. Should I keep an eye out to turn this off because it's on by default in BL2 or no?
- In Borderlands 1, the most effective elements are fire for flesh, shock for shields, and acid for armour. I notice that there are a lot more robotic enemies. Does this mean an increase in the value of corrosive damage, assuming the elements work the same?
- It seems there's a fifth element: Slag. How does this work?
- Considering what I've seen of Zer0 recently, mêlée seems to be a viable play-style now.
- I notice that health and damage values reach the hundreds of thousands.
- Roland the Soldier was pretty much the support character, but it sounds like Maya the Siren is the new support.
- In Borderlands 1, Crawmerax was the main raid boss, with a few others only worth farming for one drop. Has this changed?
- What's the level cap? [This](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/85420/what-is-the-maximum-level) and [this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/96491/i-have-hit-level-50-and-the-game-is-dropping-level-50-guns-are-these-guns-as-go) Q&A say level 50, but I saw level 61, from a source that I trust as non-hacking.

  - When did the change from 50 to 61 happen?
  - Are there special conditions to getting that raised level cap, like in Borderlands 1?
- Is there an equivalent of the Underdome in Borderlands 2?
- In Borderlands 1, you'd want to judge weapons largely by their rarity, and only replace them if they're outlevelled by 6 or more or so. Is it still the same?
- In Borderlands 1, a gripe is that a weapon that spawns with or without a sight is stuck with it. Are weapons in Borderlands 2 more customizable?

**What are the differences to combat from Borderlands to Borderlands 2?**

Comment: In response to the down-votes: http://www.quickmeme.com/meme/3u9biy/

Comment: One does not simply compile a long list of individual questions and make it a post on StackExchange without first trying to search for answers. You know, SE strives to be a good and searchable reference. In short - your list is too personal and too far from a generic question "what are main differences", which is also of questionable value.

Comment: The point isn't the list; the list of questions are suggestions of what a comprehensive answer would encompass. While I wish for comprehensive answers, I understand that that is a minor subset of the sorts of answers that (commonly) appear on here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The elements from BL1 are unchanged, so shock is good versus blue shield bars, fire against red health bars, and corrosive against yellow armor bars.  There's also explosive, which is sort of an all around element.  Slag has been added, and it increases the damage taken from other weapons instead of causing a damage-over-time effect.

The Commando class has lost many of the "turret support" effects it used to have, and most of the team healing has been moved to the Siren.  The ammo regen effects have moved to the Gunzerker class.  The classes fit similar archetypes as before, but have been tweaked significantly.

Weapons tended to be class-specific in BL1, with special skills for each weapon restricted to a particular class.  In BL2, these limitations have been removed, and any class can theoretically excel with any weapon type.

The level cap is currently 61 if you have the Ultimate Vault Hunter Upgrade Pack ($5 or included with the Season Pass).  It is 50 otherwise.

There are several "[raid bosses](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Raid_boss)" in the game, with some in the base game and each DLC adding more.  The campaign bosses can also be re-fought, and each boss tends to have an increased chance of dropping a particular legendary item.  The raid bosses in the DLC can also drop [Seraph Crystals](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Seraph), which can be traded for certain rare items.

There are several Circles of Slaughter that have 5 rounds each.  One is in the Fridge (the Bandit Circle) one is in the Ore Chasm (the Hyperion Circle) and one is paid/preorder DLC (Creature Circle).  These are similar to the Underdome from BL1.  There's also the Torgue DLC (DLC pack #2, included with the season pass) which has several arena-style fights.

Rarity is important in weapon selection, but level is also important.  It's hard to say which is the most important, or that there's a level<->rarity conversion that works throughout all 61 levels.

There is also a Golden Chest in the main hub town that can be opened with special Golden Keys you can get as rewards for certain actions (usually finding codes for them via Gearbox social media, etc).  This box will generate random items of very high rarity which tend to be very powerful.

Eridium has been added as a currency, and it is used to purchase Storage Deck Upgrades for your ammo capacity and storage capacity (backpack, bank, etc), and you can use it to fight/re-fight the raid bosses.

Comment: Oh, armour is a quantity now, like shield and red health, rather than something always present that simply reduces damage (and affects elements)? I assume Slag lasts as long as normal elements and damage numbers boosted by Slag are colour-coded purple. Commando is Axton? Circles of Slaughter sound like Circles of X from the previous game, which were series of side-quests. I assume that you equate these to the Underdome because they are repeatable, unlike in Bl1. I don't know what you mean by arena-style; PvP? Is there an indefinite amount of storage with Eridium?

Comment: @NiteCyper, I think armor is pretty similar to shields or health, it's just a bar.  Most enemies are either armor, health, or shields+health.  Axton is the Commando, yes.  I don't believe the circles are repeatable, I just remembered "wave style combat in an arena" being the Underdome.  Torgue's arena-style quests are repeatable, though.  Eridium is capped, it used to be 99, but now it is 500.

Answer (score 0):

One of the main diffs is intrduction of "badassness", complete challenges to get badass points, fill the gauge to earn a point to upgrade to things like max health, gun accuracy, reload speed, etc by a small percentage. Whereas in BL1 it was a case of upgrading weapons by getting XP using a certain weapon type, SMG, sniper rifle, etc.